# Hide time and battery status

Tags: ios8, uinavigationbar, xcode6

I have a Navigation Controller with nav bar. The issue I have is I can set the status bar to white, but once the nav bar animates onto the page, they return to black. I've tried using the following with no success:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
[UIApplication sharedApplication.setStatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;

-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
```

}

and still the time, batter status, etc return to black. I would be fine with making it completely disappear if no one can figure out what I'm doing wrong lol. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with iOS 8 the status bar gets its color from the view controller of the top most view that is currently visible. Try setting the following on the Navigation Controller (assuming the UINavigationController view is the top most view):

```
<navController>.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

If that doesn't work try adding the override to the top level UIViewController as you did (make sure its the primary view controller contained in your UIWindow.. assuming this is not your UINavigationController..]):

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

**Also**:
In the .plist file for your project, make sure the "View controller-based status bar appearance" is set to YES.

**Alternative**

If you want your

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

command to have an effect set  "View controller-based status bar appearance" to NO in your .plist file. Please note though that view controller based status bars are the wave of the future and some third party libraries (like PSPDFKit) now require this option to be enabled.

**Hiding Status Bar**

If you want to hide the status bar you can try by setting "View controller-based status bar appearance" to NO in your .plist file. Then add the following code to viewWillAppear of your main view controller:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

Comment: I tried those and got no results. I even went to the IB and selected none on top status bar but it still appears.